# Unable to install Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition

Tags: visual-web-developer

I got a problem to install the visual web developer 2008 express edition. When I starting to install this application it start installing with visual c++ runtime prerequisites it process a minute or two after that it shows an error **The folowing component could not be downloaded    
visual c++ runtime prerequisites** I read an article regarding this at http://forums.asp.net/t/1487605.aspx
It says completely remove vwd 2005 before installing vwd 2008. I did it but it display same error I have net connection also. Where I am wrong to install the application. Please suggest to overcome this problem. Thanks

Comment: This is a question about installing an application, not a programming question (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: "[...] but if your question generally covers [...]
- software tools commonly used by programmers
[...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing it through Web Platform Installer. If 2008 isn't available anymore, just install 2010, which is fully backward compatible to .Net 3.5